# Hide a collection is unhiding another collection

Tags: interface, collections

I'm new in Blender and trying to hide a collection (CTRL+H), but the it keeps unhiding a different collection. I wonder how to fix this. Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: maybe you have a collection inside a collection, it would explain why two collection get hidden when hiding one

Comment: Thank you Pons, I have two separated collections inside the Scene Collection

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/ahssQ2o.png)

Comment: can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Not necessary, it's just a misconception of how _Hide Collection_ is working (see my answer below). Unfortunately I haven't really found a documentation for this, and all shortcut lists I found on the internet seem to lack the Ctrl+H in _Object Mode_, they only list it for _Edit Mode_.

Comment: By the way, +1 for this question because it's really not obvious how it works.

Comment: thank you for this clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut key menu for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is actually labeled misunderstandably. It's not hiding the collection you click on, it hides all other collections except the one you click on - so it's more like "Isolate Collection". Your screen capture doesn't show that because you can only see objects there, no collections.

For example: I have four text objects, showing the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4. Object 1 is in collection 1, 2 in collection 2, 3 in 3 and the 4 is in no collection (apart from the top level Scene Collection).

As you can see in the following screen capture, with the *Hide Collection* menu, always the collection I click on stays visible while all others are hidden. The number 4 which is in no collection stays visible all the time.

By the way, if you have selected an object, the dot to the left of the collection name indicates in which collection it is - in your screen capture you can see, when you click on the name with the dot, the selected tree appears. When you click on the other name, the unselected tree appears. So, the *Hide Collection* tool actually means: *Select the collection you want to see and hide all others*.

If you want to unhide all collections, go to the *Outliner* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Note: this only works if the *Display Mode* of the *Outliner* window is set to *View Layer* (usually the default setting).

[image: hide collection]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gordon! now it's clear why Blender hides the other objects. But unfortunately when I press Alt + H in the outliner nothing happens. Although I've moved my objects to the collections, the collections still empty as you can see on the screenshot [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/6dpkp5s.png)

Comment: @douglasfigueira Your collections are not empty (I guess). Your _Outliner_ window's _Display Mode_ is switched to _Scenes_, where the contents of your scene is grouped by datablock types, so it shows only collections under "Scene Collection", and all objects under "Objects". Switch the _Display Mode_ to _View Layer_ to see the default grouping: [Outliner Display Modes](https://pasteall.org/pic/bb69ee88e677477da86214bad26ab2e6)

Comment: @douglasfigueira The _Unhide All_ option with Alt+H only works in the _View Layer_ display mode. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: @douglasfigueira If this helped you, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: thank you now on View Layer mode is working great!